# Array just keeps adding object and memory Crash

Tags: ios, arrays, memory

I am recently having a memory crash and I am suspecting that I am failing to empty the array, This is my code for the array

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   allImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *location=@"Bottoms";
    NSString *fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:location];
    NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: fPath];
    collectionBottoms.delegate =self;
    collectionBottoms.dataSource=self;
    for(NSString *str in directoryContent){
        NSLog(@"i");
        NSString *finalFilePath = [fPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:str];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:finalFilePath];
        if(data)
        {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            [allImagesArray addObject:image];
            NSLog(@"array:%@",[allImagesArray description]);

        }}
}
```

Ho can I free the memory by releasing the object in the array?

Comment: remove image from array when you don't need them?

Comment: Exactly...as long as they are in the array they will be alive.

Comment: I can't find a place to do that,  I know you put the code                 `[allImagesArray removeAllObjects];
NSLog(@"%@", allImagesArray);}`but cannot find a good place to put it.  I want to save the picture first to save to document however if I put this above code it just deletes the picture that I just took.

Comment: Then don't use that method.  What's wrong with `removeObject:` or `removeObjectAtIndex:`?  It would be pretty foolish to have an array where you could only remove every object, don't you think?

Comment: What should I use instead, I cannot a way to do this.

Comment: Well, the best thing to do would be to not store every image in an array.  This will quickly eat up your usable memory.

Comment: If you don't actually need all of the images in the array, just use [allImagesArray removeOjbect: image];

Comment: I suggest you load your images as they are needed, not all at once.

Answer (score 1):

You save the image array in Plist. After save you just re initialize your array it will clear the memory in array. Then are you using ARC or not? Because ARC is more comfortable for this. Then re-initialze or removeAllObject from array in -viewWillDisappear

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this image array, `allImagesArray`,  when the view is visible then put this code in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` methods of `UIViewController`.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

   allImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *location=@"Bottoms";
    NSString *fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:location];
    NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: fPath];
    collectionBottoms.delegate =self;
    collectionBottoms.dataSource=self;
    for(NSString *str in directoryContent){
        NSLog(@"i");
        NSString *finalFilePath = [fPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:str];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:finalFilePath];
        if(data)
        {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            [allImagesArray addObject:image];
            NSLog(@"array:%@",[allImagesArray description]);

        }
    }
}
```

And, then release it in viewWillDisappear/viewDidDisappear methods of `UIViewController`.

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    [allImagesArray removeAllObjects];
    //[allImagesArray release]; // (Uncomment) Call this only if you are not using ARC.
}
```

Alternatively, a **quick, dirty but safe** fix is (without knowing your usage of `allImagesArray`) -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

     // Remove previously added objects.
     if (allImagesArray != nil && allImagesArray.count > 0) {
            [allImagesArray removeAllObjects];
     }
     // Allocate memory if not done earlier (i.e. first time).
     if (allImagesArray == nil) {
        allImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     }

     // Rest of your code as stated in your question
}
```

Comment: I don't get the code that is written at the bottom which line should I put this and why is it viewWillappear not viewdidload?

Comment: Clarified the code for alternative approach above. `viewWillAppear` is called everytime view is presented on screen and `viewDidDisappear` when its removed of screen. These are `UIViewController` methods. Read official docs for more details here - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi Just release the memory once object works is over. Here is the code for you.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   allImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *location=@"Bottoms";
    NSString *fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:location];
    NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: fPath];
    collectionBottoms.delegate =self;
    collectionBottoms.dataSource=self;
    for(NSString *str in directoryContent)
    {
        NSString *finalFilePath = [fPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:str];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:finalFilePath];
        if(data)
        {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            [allImagesArray addObject:image];
            NSLog(@"array:%@",[allImagesArray description]);
        image = nil;

        }
    finalFilePath=nil;
    data=nil;
   }

 paths= nil;
 documentsDirectory= nil;
 location= nil;
 fPath= nil;
 directoryContent = nil;
}
```

Comment: This looks like it will help and it does decrease the memory but it still builds up after taking many photo.  Does this have problems with the camera code or something else.  This is my whole code https://github.com/laryufk/Helper/tree/master for the camera is there something wrong.

Comment: You have to nil or release the object once its works get over. So you can have check your code release the memory.